# Unable to Install GTK3.4(libgtk-3.so.0) to run firefox in AWS ec2

Tags: amazon-web-services, selenium, firefox, amazon-ec2, gtk3

I am trying to run my selenium script which has been developed in Selenium 2.53.0 using firefox 46 in a headless AWS linux server. AWS has GTK2.0 and Firefox 46 is compatible with GTK3.4 and above. 
I tried to install GTK 3.4 from the given links and it is installed but still I am getting error

```
XPCOMGlueLoad error for file /usr/local/firefox/libmozgtk.so:
libgtk-3.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Couldn't load XPCOM.
```

I do not have libgtk-3.so.0 installed in my system hence the error. If somebidy can help me on how to upgrade/install GTK 3.4 along with the said libraries to run my firefox in AWS EC2 server it will be really helpful.
The Links i have used : http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/gnome/sources/gtk+/3.4/gtk+-3.4.0.tar.xz
 ftp://fr2.rpmfind.net/linux/fedora/linux/development/rawhide/Everything/x86_64/os/Packages/g/gtk3-3.22.15-2.fc27.x86_64.rpm
to install the GTK3
Installed Firefox 46 using the Code https://gist.github.com/joekiller/4144838 from here.

Thanks.